# Prove by induction $(n+1) + (n + 2) +\dots + (2n - 1 ) + (2n) = \frac{n(3n + 1)}{2}$, $n \geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, arithmetic-progressions

> Prove by induction that 
>   $(n+1) + (n + 2) +\dots + (2n - 1 ) + (2n) = \dfrac{n(3n + 1)}{2}$
>   for $n \geq 1$.

I tried to add $(2(k+1)-1) + (2(k+1))$ to both sides and got stuck.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't forget that the first term changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the inductive step we start from
$$(n+1) + (n + 2) +\dots+ (2n – 1 ) + (2n) = n(3n + 1)/2.$$
We add $ (2(n+1)-1) + (2(n+1))$ to both sides 
**AND** we subtract $n+1$ from both sides.
Then we verify that the right hand side is equal to 
$$ (n+1)(3(n+1) + 1)/2.$$
Can you take it form here?

Comment: Yes, I was editing was answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sneaky, show the easier $s(n) := \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and then subtract $s(n)$ from $s(2n)$.